# Delphi get cookies from THTTPRIO

Tags: delphi, cef4delphi

I have an SOAP Webservice that has a Login method, currently after I call it the website gets opened by the TWebBrowser control and use the session cookie from the webservice.
But now I try to migrate to CEF4DELPHI instead of TWebBrowser.
I try to get the cookie over `InternetGetCookie` but I always get error 259 (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) back.
The problem is also that the cookie name can vary so I don`t know always the cookie name.
How can I get all cookies from a specific domain or is it possible to get the complete response header? I only find a hook for before the request is send.

Comment: If HTTPRIO doesn't give access to the cookies, just switch to another HTTP component.

Comment: Open the CookieVisitor demo in CEF4Delphi. It has all the code you need to read the session cookies.